# Tensorflow - Where's the input node for my Convolutional Neural Network?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I've managed to build a Convolutional Neural Network in my PC using the Python interface for Tensorflow, and now I want to use said CNN for Android's Tensorflow. When I looked at the list of the nodes in the model with the `tf.GraphDef()` (`gf.ParseFromString(open('F:/python_machine_learning_codes/graph_optimized.pb','rb').read())`, then `[n.name + '=>' +  n.op for n in gf.node]`), however, I got these:

```
['enqueue_input/random_shuffle_queue=>RandomShuffleQueueV2',
 'random_shuffle_queue_DequeueMany/n=>Const',
 'random_shuffle_queue_DequeueMany=>QueueDequeueManyV2',
 'Reshape/shape=>Const',
 'Reshape=>Reshape',
 #... the rest of the CNN's processing layers up to...
 'softmax_tensor=>Softmax']
```

I know the node named `softmax_tensor` is the output node (that's what I use to see the results), but which one of the above is the input node?

Comment: From the name, the "enqueue_input" node seems like a good candidate...

Comment: I tried that and got this exception: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No OpKernel was registered to support Op 'RandomShuffleQueueV2' with these attrs.  Registered devices: [CPU], Registered kernels:
                                                                      <no registered kernels>`.

By the way, the node was shaped like this in the traceback: `[[Node: enqueue_input/random_shuffle_queue = RandomShuffleQueueV2[capacity=1000, component_types=[DT_INT64, DT_INT32, DT_FLOAT], container="", min_after_dequeue=250, seed=1, seed2=4, shapes=[[], [], [64,64,3]], shared_name=""]()]]`

Comment: This is about you don't have implementation of operation `RandomShuffleQueueV2` for `[CPU]` on device, and thus you can't launch your graph.

Comment: I trained the neural network with the code `with tf.device("/gpu:0"): tf.app.run()`. Does this play a part in the problem?

Comment: Also,  OpenCV's dnn_modern module doesn't recognize `RandomShuffleQueueV2` either.

Answer (score 0):

I had been going through that all wrong, it turned out. The Graph freezing code I used back then was not the one for exporting. After upgrading into the latest Tensorflow version, I just had to do this:

```
feature_spec = {"x": tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=[None, 64*64*3])}
serving_input_fn = tf.estimator.export.build_raw_serving_input_receiver_fn(feature_spec)
model_version_path = mnist_classifier.export_savedmodel(
    "F:/python_machine_learning_codes/estimator_exported_model",
    serving_input_receiver_fn = serving_input_fn,
    assets_extra=None,
    as_text=False,
    checkpoint_path=None
    )
```

And the Placeholder node properly shows up at the beginning of the graph and can be used as the input node.